# I want all installed applications to automatically go to my secondary hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, external-hard-drive

I just made a new computer and I want my SSD to only have the operating system and my other hard drive to have everything else. For some installs, it does not let you choose which drive to install to. Is there a way to have all applications automatically install to my secondary drive? 
Jason

Comment: No in general. Some software may use hardcoded paths or some path part (or paths relative to %SYSTEMROOT%, for example).

Comment: I use Windows 64-bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all software products whose default installation folder is not hardwired
into the installation program, you may change the default folder as follows:

- Run `regedit`
- Navigate to the key
  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion`
- Double-click and set the value of `ProgramFilesDir` to the new folder
- For 64-bit Windows, consider also setting `ProgramFilesDir (x86)`.

Before doing any registry work, create a System Restore point as backup.